# Problema en usar import y export en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente archivo llamado **constantes.js**. El código es:

```
export const pi = Math.PI;
```

También tengo este otro código en otro fichero (**modulo.js**):

```
import {pi} from './constantes.js';
```

Este módulo lo he enlazado a mi documento html de la siguiente manera :

Luego intento ver el resultado por consola y me sale el siguiente error:

```
Se declara "pi", pero su valor no se lee nunca.ts(6133)
```

Es decir no me permite hacer la importación. Ya intente varias soluciones como ejecutar en el servidor local y en la carpeta del servidor. Por favor, ¿alguien tiene alguna solución?

Comment: Lo de "Se declara "pi", pero su valor no se lee nunca.ts(6133)" no es un error, sino una advertencia del _language server_ que no tendría que aparecer por fuera de tu entorno de desarrollo. Además, ya que estás usando módulos de ES6, deberías incluir también el código HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Exportar una variable no tiene mucho sentido (a menos que sea algo especifico), lo ideal sería que crees o establezcas un functional component o clase si queires, aunque no deberían usarse, y que esa funcion retorne "p" con su respectivo valor. Luego puedes utilizar p en cualquier parte de tu código. En caso de que no te funcione esto, manda captura del código entero y que renedrizas en el main.jsx

ejemplo de p como componente

```
//constantes.js

export const numeroPi=()=>{

let p = Math.pi;

console.log(p);

return p

}
//tambien podrias hacer un export default numeroPI;


//modulo.js

import {numeroPI} from './constantes.js';

const componente=()=>{

<numeroPI /> //muestra por consola el valor de pi una vez

<numeroPI /> //muestra por consola el valor de pi una vez

<numeroPI /> //muestra por consola el valor de pi una vez

//puedes usar el valor de PI infinidad de veces
}
```

Tambien puedes utilizar archivos de barril y en ellos, establecer valores fijos y acceder desde ahí, para eso te dejo que leas, quizá te puede servir: [https://es.linkedin.com/learning/typescript-avanzado/agrupacion-de-modulos-con-barrel-files#:~:text=Los%20archivos%20barril%20o%20barrel,donde%20queremos%20aplicar%20este%20concepto](https://es.linkedin.com/learning/typescript-avanzado/agrupacion-de-modulos-con-barrel-files#:%7E:text=Los%20archivos%20barril%20o%20barrel,donde%20queremos%20aplicar%20este%20concepto).